# How can I disable network connectivity to a particular port or IP address in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking

How can I disable network connectivity to a particular port or IP address on Windows?

If my Windows client tries to connect to a server with this IP address, I want it to fail the connection immediately rather than wait for a timeout period.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Plz elaborate.. It is not clear whether you wish to do it on the windows machine itself or remotely?

Comment: Windows XP and Windows 7

Comment: Ideally on the remote server or network device that is between all the windows client computers to the server. Or if that is not possible locally on client windows computer.

Answer (score 3):

Configure your firewall to block access to that IP address.

In *Windows 7*:

1. Open **Control Panel**, **Windows Firewall**.
2. On the left, press **Advanced settings**.
3. On the left, select **Outbound Rules**.
4. On the right, press **New Rule...**
5. Select **Custom** and press **Next**.
6. Select **All programs** and press **Next**.
7. Select **Protocol type: Any** and press **Next**.
8. Under **Which remote IP addresses does this rule apply to**, select **These IP addresses** and press **Add...**
9. Select **This IP address or subnet**, type the IP address and press **OK**.
10. Press **Next**.
11. Select **Block the connection** and press **Next**.
12. Tick **Domain**, **Private** and **Public** and press **Next**.
13. Type a name and description for this rule and press **Finish**.

You may want to make an inbound rule with the same properties if you're concerned about the server contacting you.