# Block all inbound traffic except one IP using windows firewall rules

Tags: windows, security, firewall, iptables, windows-server-2008

I have no problem doing this in linux. I just write an iptable to block all traffic and another one after to allow a specific IP. However it doesn't look to be that easy on Windows. I did the exact same thing but it looks like the second rules doesn't take over the first one like in IPTABLES.
So any idea how to do this? If possible only using windows firewall rules...
Thank you

Comment: See this answer http://serverfault.com/a/130768/229754

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Make One Exception to a Windows Firewall Outbound Rule](http://superuser.com/questions/590243/how-to-make-one-exception-to-a-windows-firewall-outbound-rule)