# Windows Firewall Inbound Rule - Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, firewall

I'm trying to create a PS script that creates a Windows firewall rule, blocking the port "6672" for a certain .exe file on an INBOUND connection but lets me have the option to whitelist certain IPs.

The way to do this manually means I have to block the port (6672) for my .exe file completely to ALL IP's then add a range leaving out the IP's I want to whitelist.

For Example if I want to add "192.168.0.3" I have to set a range on the rule for "0.0.0.0" to "192.168.0.2" then another for "192.168.0.4" to "255.255.255.255".
The reason I have to do it this was it that in Windows firewall it looks like you cannot whitelist single IP's from a block rule and block rules override any allow rules.

So back to my original point, I'm really struggling for ideas on how to resolve this at the moment as I can't find a workaround. Is there a way anybody knows of to be able to exclude certain IP's from a rule or how to make an allow rule be prioritised over a block rule?

**EDIT**

So i have THIS CODE:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "GTAO" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 6672 -Protocol UDP -Action Block
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "GTAO" -Direction Outbound -LocalPort 6672 -Protocol UDP -Action Block
```

I basically want something like this to override the previous rule creating a "whitelist" on this rule for individual IP's

```
$UIP = Read-Host "Enter IP to whitelist"
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "GTA$UIP" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 6672 -Protocol UDP -Action Allow -RemoteAddress $UIP
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a PS specific issue, but a 'How do I make WF do X or Y that it was not designed for.'

Very similar to this discussion and suggestions, some of which you have already hinted at.

> How to Make One Exception to a Windows Firewall Outbound Rule
>
> [How to Make One Exception to a Windows Firewall Outbound Rule](https://superuser.com/questions/590243/how-to-make-one-exception-to-a-windows-firewall-outbound-rule)
>
> According to the Windows Firewall documentation, block rules always
>   take precedence over allow rules, therefore even if your allow rule
>   looks more specific than a block rule, the allow rule will not work,
>   and the traffic matching both allow and block rules will be blocked.
>   The option “Allow this firewall rule to override block rules” is
>   available only for rules which require IPSec, and is not available for
>   outbound rules.
>
> The only thing you could do with Windows Firewall to achieve something
>   close to what you need is to switch the default behavior for outbound
>   connections to “Block”, then add explicit allow rules for all outbound
>   connections that you need (not just for that single program).
>   Alternatively, you can look for third-party firewall software with
>   more features.
>
> ... you can make the above
>   rule for a single program as well, simply set the rule for a program
>   not all programs.
>
> so you set up 2 or more rules (depending on how many ip addresses you
>   want to allow) and block all others. so for example if you only want
>   to allow
>
> 10.10.10.10
>
> and
>
> 20.20.20.20
>
> you set up rules:
>
> block from 0.0.0.0 to 10.10.10.9 and 10.10.10.11 to 20.20.20.19 and
>   20.20.20.21 to 255.255.255.255

Comment: That actually makes alot of sense.
Oh man, now i have to think of how to get the ip ranges as a variable output... Regex here we come! xD