# Remove all firewall rules except for the browser

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firewall

I want to remove all firewall rules and only set rules to allow a connections, basically have all connections blocked except for those I whitelist like a chrome browser. I've reset the windows defender firewall rules to default.

[image: default rules]

I proceeded to remove all those and rules.

[image: removed rules]

I then change go to the properties tab and set outbound connections to block by default

[image]

and add a rule to allow connections inbound and outbound from google chrome.

[image]

But after all this I can't access internet on google chrome.
with the default rules it chrome works until I set outbound connections to default to blocking. I'm not understanding why this is the case. I only want google chrome to access the internet.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure what you mean. The Google chrome rule is what I'm adding as the exception to blocking all outgoing connections.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Make One Exception to a Windows Firewall Outbound Rule](https://superuser.com/questions/590243/how-to-make-one-exception-to-a-windows-firewall-outbound-rule)

Comment: @Ramhound the question you doesn't answer my question. my problem is about why I still can't access internet through chrome even after it is allowed in the last picture you can see this.